# How to display data from XML file to ListView using LINQ to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq, lambda

I'm having an xml file like

```
<Root>
 <Child val1="1" val2="2"/>
 <Child val1="1" val2="3"/>
 <Child val1="2" val2="4"/>
</Root>
```

i need to display the data from the Xml file to  a Listview like

[image]

(Added `A` to index value)

Now i'm using like

1.Stores the data in an `XmlNodesList`

2.Then iterate through the `nodeslist` and add the attribute value to the list view

Here i can not use `Dictionary<String,String>` as a temporary storage because there exist multiple keys with same name.

Is there any idea to do this using `LINQ to XML`.?

Comment: @ abatishchev : Yes... Edited title :-)

Comment: It's rather better to use tags instead of title ;)

Comment: btw, where from `A1,A2,A3` comes?

Comment: @ abatishchev : ` 1,2,3` are the index value( for loop  ("A"+(Index+1).ToString())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without LINQ:

```
var doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("Root/Child");

for (int i = 0; i < nodes.Count; i++)
{
    var n = nodes[i];
    var index = String.Format("A{0}", i + 1);
    var column1 = n.Attributes["val1"].Value;
    var column2 = n.Attributes["val1"].Value;

    // use variables to add an item to ListView
}
```

Using LINQ:

```
using System.Linq;

var doc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xml);

var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("Root/Child");
var arr = nodes
    .OfType<XmlNode>()
    .ToArray();

var result = arr
    .Select(n =>
        new
        {
            ClNo = String.Format("A{0}", Array.IndexOf(arr, n) +1),
            Val1 = n.Attributes["val1"].Value,
            Val2 = n.Attributes["val2"].Value,
        });

ListView list = new ListView();
ListViewItem[] items = result
    .Select(r => new ListViewItem(new[] { r.ClNo, r.Val1, r.Val2 })
    .ToArray();
list.Items.AddRange(items);
```

Comment: @abatishchev : `Populate()` - i do not understand this

Comment: I mean that `Populate()` returns `XmlNodeList` data from your XML file, e.g. `doc.SelectNodes("root/child");`

Comment: @abatishchev: Thank you , but its throwing an error like `Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.` 
i'm using .NET 3.5 frame work

Comment: @ abatishchev : No also its throwing the same error. I think we can not use ListView property( ColumnName) as an anonymous type variable

Comment: @Pramodh: What error and what string? The code works fine for me!

Comment: @ abatishchev : You are right. i thought the `query` directly dump the data to the list view. Here we need to iterate through `result` to dump the data to the list view . Am i right??

Comment: @Pramodh: If use anonymous type and lambda - yes

Comment: @ abatishchev : The `Without LINQ` is some what like what i'm using now.

Comment: @ abatishchev  : its throwing some error in `new ListViewItem(r.ClNo, r.Val1, r.Val2) `  like `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewItem(string, string, System.Windows.Forms.ListViewGroup)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: @Pramodh: I edited my post. I thought that constructor accepts `params string[]` but indeed it accepts just `string[]`

Comment: @abatishchev : how about this `int i = 1;ListViewItem[] item = XDocument.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\foo.xml").Descendants("Child").Select(X => new{a = X.Attribute("val1").Value,b = X.Attribute("Val2").Value}).Select(X => new ListViewItem(new String[] {"A"+(i++).ToString(), X.a, X.b})).ToArray(); listView1.Items.AddRange(item);`